# imacros how do I play another javascript file after finish running a javascript function

Tags: javascript, imacros

I created a javascript file with codes in it and is working fine on imacros. but the thing is I need to execute another javascript function on another javascript file. i tried different things but I can't make it work.

my script is something like this

```
myfunction ();
iimPlay (anotherFIle.js);
```

so my function plays some code that I did which is working fine. But when it's time to execute anotherFile.js it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, it is that you want to load another javascript file using a function, to be able to execute functions defined in this file. This can be done using the following function.

```
function loadJSFile(url){
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.setAttribute('src', url);
   script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

And load (play) the file like this:

```
loadJSFile("anotherFile.js");
```

(don't forget the quotes)

Comment: This worked at the beginning... but now FF complains about missing "document" object! How is it possible? What did I do???

Answer (score 1):

You can add anotherFIle.js to bookmarks and then call it by iimPlay("CODE:URL GOTO=[bookmark_link]"). If anotherFIle.js in root folder of iMacros, try this:

```
myfunction ();    
iimPlay("CODE:URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=anotherFIle.js",60);
```

Comment: This works... but it also results in calling the script twice! Why?