# How do I run an external javascript on Imacros?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am very new with Imacros and javascript and I already learn a few things here. But I still got some problems..

I want to execute different javascript file on one single imacros file. The javascript is too long if I place it in a single file so I decided to put some functions on a separate .js file.

so I have

imacrosFile.iim = this is where I want all the functions from different .js files to be executed

my different .js files where functions are coded
script1.js
script2.js
script3.js
script4.js

Thanks,

Comment: you can't do this from IIM file

Answer (score 0):

in JS file place

```
iimPlay("macro1.iim")
iimPlay("macro2.iim")
```

And make sure that each macro you play like this is located with #Current.iim macro.

Comment: this does not answer the question, which is related to calling JS macros, not IIM macros. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511047/imacros-how-do-i-play-another-javascript-file-after-finish-running-a-javascript/17511813#17511813

Comment: It can be done by saving .js files in bookmarks and executing them with URL GOTO=bookmarkedlink command.